# Renamed column for hive parquet table can't be read by Spark HiveContext

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have an external table in Hive, the table format is parquet

We have renamed column using hive Alter table change column ( from id to empid) statement and

`set parquet.column.index.access = true`.

> Table name : xyz
>   old column name : id
>   new column name emp_id

The SQL `select emp_id from xyz` is working fine in hive 
I would to query the table through spark `HiveContext`

I set the property of

```
 hc.setConf("parquet.column.index.access", "true")
```

But `hc.sql("select emp_id from xyz")`, all the `emp_id` are null

Comment: column `id` is partition column? and what was the command used to rename?

Comment: Thanks @RamPrasadG for the reply. `id` is not partion column, and the command to rename the column is: `alter table xyz change id emp_id string`